# which event listener to call when user enters the text in the text field in a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing UI using html and jquery.
I have a html table which has multiple columns, Product1 and Product2 columns holds the drop down list.
I want **to validate Product1 and Product2 fields when user enters text in the Description field.**

Currently with the below code, i'm checking if user selects same values in dropdown list for each row Product1 and Product2 and 
show the dialog pop up saying "Product1 and Product2 cannot have same value".
**How to call the below logic when user enters text in the Description field instead of calling when user changes the dropdown list**(**$("select").change..)**

**sample code:**

```
$("select").change(function() 
       {   
       var row = $(this).closest("tr");
       var product1_drop = $('.product1',row).val();
       var product2_drop = $('.product2',row).val();
       if(product1_drop == product2_drop ){       
            alert('Product1 and Product2 cannot have same value');
      }
   });
```

Demo link : http://plnkr.co/edit/dFjOUUtcvfRcRyZrVdrw?p=preview

--EDITED--

**Note** : User can enter the values in the fields in any sequence but i want to validate when there is a text in the Description field.Example, user can select value in Product1 and enter OrderID and Description then Select value in Product2, so now as it has value in the Description field it has to check the condition..If user has not entered anything in the Description field then it should not check the condition..

Comment: Did you try simply changing the initial selector to match the input? If so, what went wrong?

Comment: I think i need to call some listener which is called every time when user enters a text in the Description field of the table. The logic i have written in the above shown change(..) function works perfectly.

Comment: Right so you need to target that `<input>` instead of  `<select>`. Add a class and use that class as selector

Comment: yeah, but in my table i have multiple text fields, i want to call only when user enters the text in the Description field...

Comment: And adding a class to those fields would simplify targeting them with  class selector. Sounds like you need to study up on how to use jQuery and css selectors https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dganenco/v6n2cqf4/1/) for you. As a summary you need to bind input handler for both products and description field as well, and call validate method for any event.

```
$("select").change(function() {   
         var row = $(this).closest("tr");
         var product1_drop = $('.product1',row).val();
         var product2_drop = $('.product2',row).val();
         var descValue = $('input[name="description"]').val();
                validate(product1_drop,product2_drop, descValue);
       });

        $('input[name="description"]').on('input', function(e){
          var row = $(this).closest("tr");
          var product1_drop = $('.product1',row).val();
            var product2_drop = $('.product2',row).val();
            validate(product1_drop,product2_drop, $(this).val());
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the "input" event:

```
$("#productTable input[name=description]").on("input", function validate() {
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  var product1_drop = $(".product1", row).val();
  var product2_drop = $(".product2", row).val();
  if (product1_drop == product2_drop) {
    alert("Product1 and Product2 cannot have same value");
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ABFfbH0yb4MOFoJvN94v?p=preview

The difference between the "change" event and the "input" event is that "change" is fired when the input looses the focus, while "input" whenever its content changes.

EDIT accordingly to @user3684675's update:

You can extract the "validate" function and call it both when the description and the products change:

```
$("#productTable input[name=description]").on("input", validate);
$("#productTable select").on("change, validate);
```

Inside the "validate" function you should then check that the description is not empty:

```
if (!$("input[name=description", row).val()) return;
```